# Emacs Org-Mode: Auto-complete. Display UTF-8 Characters in Popup

Tags: emacs, utf-8, elisp, org-mode

Org user who relies heavily on the `org-pretty-entities` feature to display portions of equations and chemical formulas.
Recently, I created a custom dictionary for the purpose of using it with `auto-complete.el` and `popup.el`. **I was curious if there is an existing Solution
to display UTF-8 characters in the auto-complete popup window that mimics the functionality of `org-pretty-entities`?** If not, how could something
similar be accomplished? Thanks in advance.

*Bonus Points:*
I have dozens of formulas stored under `ac-dictionary-files` that utilize subscripts; E.g:

- H_{2}O
- H_{2}SO_{3}
- H_{2}PO_{4}^{-}

Upon typing `H_` the complete list of those that begin with H are shown (and will complete successfully), however, typing the opening bracket `{` causes the list to list to close and completion to fail.

Some of the entries ("`H_`" for example) have such a numerous amount of completions it would take more key strokes (repeatedly pressing the `TAB` key)
than to type the formula itself. What can be changed to enable the use and/or recognition of the `{` `}` characters by prediction?